# Graphics2D to paint a line on a map

Tags: java, overlay, graphics2d

I'm trying to paint a path on a map using coordinates. I'm trying to use GeneralPath but it doesn't create a line just bunch of dots where lat/long coordinates are. How do I connect them or is there something else that I can use? Not really familiar with Graphics2D..

```
region.add(new GeoPosition(47.2971, -122.3822));
region.add(new GeoPosition(47.2975, -122.3701));
region.add(new GeoPosition(47.3006, -122.3535));
region.add(new GeoPosition(47.2899, -122.3356));
region.add(new GeoPosition(47.2895, -122.3111));
region.add(new GeoPosition(47.2903, -122.2989));
region.add(new GeoPosition(47.2929, -122.2921));
region.add(new GeoPosition(47.2914, -122.2920));
region.add(new GeoPosition(47.2934, -122.2883));


Painter<JXMapViewer> overlay = new Painter<JXMapViewer>() {
    public void paint(Graphics2D g, JXMapViewer map, int w, int h) {
        g = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        //convert from viewport to world bitmap
        Rectangle rect = map.getViewportBounds();
        g.translate(-rect.x, -rect.y);          
        GeneralPath path = new GeneralPath();
        //Polygon poly = new Polygon();
        for(GeoPosition gp : region) {
            //convert geo to world bitmap pixel
            mapViewer.setZoom(60);
            Point2D pt = map.getTileFactory().geoToPixel(gp, map.getZoom());
            //poly.addPoint((int)pt.getX(),(int)pt.getY());
            path.moveTo((int)pt.getX(),(int)pt.getY());
            path.lineTo((int)pt.getX(),(int)pt.getY());                                                                         
        }           
        //do the drawing
        g.setColor(new Color(255,0,0,100));
        g.fill(path);           
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.draw(path);           
        g.dispose();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need only a single moveTo(...) method to start the drawing of the line. Then you do multiple lineTo(...) method to draw the actual line.

Here is an example I found on the web a long time ago:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;

public class GraphicPane extends JFrame
{
    public GraphicPane()
    {
        super("polygon");

        this.setSize(600,600);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        MyPolygon mypolygon = new MyPolygon();
        getContentPane().add(mypolygon);

        this.setVisible(true);

        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e){}

        mypolygon.move();
    }

    class MyPolygon extends JPanel
    {
        Point[] p;
        GeneralPath shape;

        public MyPolygon()
        {
            p=new Point[4];
            p[0]=new Point(10,10);
            p[1]=new Point(100,10);
            p[2]=new Point(170,170);
            p[3]=new Point(80,180);
            shape =new GeneralPath();
        }

        public void move()
        {
            int x=300;
            int y=200;
            p[0].setLocation(x, y);
            shape = new GeneralPath();
            repaint();
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics grap)
        {
            super.paintComponent(grap);

            Graphics2D grap2D=(Graphics2D)grap;

            shape.moveTo((float)p[0].getX(),(float)p[0].getY());

            for(int i=1;i<p.length;i++)
            {
                shape.lineTo((float)p[i].getX(),(float)p[i].getY());
            }

            shape.closePath();
            grap2D.setColor(Color.red);
            grap2D.draw(shape);
            grap2D.setColor(Color.blue);
            grap2D.fill(shape);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
          GraphicPane graph = new GraphicPane();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. While waiting for a reply I've been doing research and found similar example. However, moving moveTo line out of the loop fixes part of the problem but creates a new one : ) . Where the first coordinate is (p[0]), instead of just putting a start of line of the path, the line goes to infinity in the opposite direction. So it creates line (connects the dots), but the first coordinate applied to moveTo goes infinity. I hope that makes sense. I wonder if there's something I need to set to fix it...

Comment: Do you have a closePath()? Is your problem the translate()? Start with something simple. Get rid of the translate(), get rid of the zoom(). I'm no expert but you have a working example so you can compare something that works with something that doesn't to see what the difference is. Once you find out what is different you can ask a more specific question and post your SSCCE (http://sscce.org) demonstrating the problem and maybe someone else will help.

Comment: I don't have closePath. I tried using closePath but it closes the path of the coordinates, so it creates a closed loop. I need a line that will show just the path. Not sure what translate() is? Your example above creates a polygon, that's not what I need. If I put closePath() in my code it will create a shape possibly a polygon. All I want is a LINE. I'm not familiar with paint and graphics, maybe I'm using the wrong class... any help would be nice

Comment: camickr means you need to call the moveTo() just once for the first point and then use lineTo() only. Each your moveTo() call juts moves position and draws the line in the same point.

Comment: I mentioned in my first comment that I did changed that.. But it partially fixed my problem. It connects my dots into line, but the first coordinates goes into infinite line to the left.

Comment: @tasha, you've been given help. You haven't posted a SSCCE, so we can't give more help. You get what you give.